# DataTable Select: Expression with a space problem

Tags: c#, string, select, datatable, expression

### Situation:

Hello! I have a little problem in a C# project. I am using the Select method from a DataTable object and using an expression to get what I want but I am having some trouble with a space in one of the strings I am using for the expression.

So here is a code sample of what I have:

```
DataTable table;
//...  
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("[" + columnNameStr + "]" + " LIKE '*" + searchStr + "*'");
//...
```

The string ***searchStr*** can have a white space in it. So for example, if you have a name such as *Bob Dude* in ***searchStr*** and the string should be *Dude Bob* instead the select expression will not return any result.

---

### Question:

What is the expression I need to use if I want to get a result when the words in ***searchStr*** are not necessarily in the right order to get a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your search string on spaces, and then build your expression string in a loop using OR. 
Something along these lines might work for you:

```
var searchStr = "Bob Dude";
var splitSearchString = searchStr.Split(' ');
var columnNameStr = "Name";
var expression = new List<string>();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
//...  
foreach (var searchElement in splitSearchString)
{
    expression.Add(
        string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '*{1}*'", columnNameStr, searchElement));
}
var searchExpressionString = string.Join(" OR ", expression.ToArray());
DataRow[] rows = table.Select(searchExpressionString);
```

Comment: Note that if you're going to be building a select expression dynamically, you'll need to preprocess each of the search elements to deal with single quotes and square brackets and probably other characters I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 4):

Another simpler way worked for me.

Say the searchStr is `"Hello World".`

```
DataTable.Select("ColumnName" + "'" + searchStr + "'");
```

the key is add a single quote `(')` before & after the search string.